# When Scrapy iterates through a list of hrefs, why are scraped items not displayed in order?

Tags: scrapy

When Scrapy iterates through a list of hrefs found on a page, why does it start displaying scraped items somewhere in the middle of the list and not with the first href?

I'm pulling state library info from a list of links found on this page: http://www.publiclibraries.com/.

The xpath I use is this:

```
//div/div/div/table/tr/td/a/@href
```

The code seems to work fine, but I'm wondering why, when the scraped items are displayed, Scrapy seems to start with Kentucky, Louisiana, Mississippi or Missouri. Which one it actually shows first is not consistent, but it does eventually show all the states (just not in the order found on the page).

Why is it not starting with Alamabama? Does this have something to with the threading? If so, is there way to force Scrapy to show them in the order they appear on the initial page?

Spider code:

```
import scrapy
import logging

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from tutorial.items import LibAddressItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "us-pub-lib-physical_addresses"
    allowed_domains = ["publiclibraries.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.publiclibraries.com/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print "#################################################################"
        print response.url
        print "Top level states list"
        print "#################################################################"

        for href in response.xpath("//div/div/div/table/tr/td/a/@href"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_state_libs)

    count = 0
    def parse_state_libs(self, response):
        print "#################################################################"
        print response.url
        print "#################################################################"

        for sel in response.xpath('//div/div/div/table/tr'):
            item = LibAddressItem()
            item['city'] = sel.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['library'] = sel.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['address'] = sel.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['zip_code'] = sel.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['phone'] = sel.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            self.count = self.count + 1
            yield item

        print "#####################################"
        print "The number of libraries found so far:"
        print self.count
        print "#####################################"
```

LibAddressItem:

```
import scrapy

class LibAddressItem(scrapy.Item):
    city = scrapy.Field()
    state = scrapy.Field()
    library = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
    zip_code = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
```

Example of initially displayed items:

```
2015-11-19 13:59:57 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.publiclibraries.com/> (referer: None)
#################################################################
http://www.publiclibraries.com/
Top level states list
#################################################################
2015-11-19 13:59:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm> (referer: http://www.publiclibraries.com/)
#################################################################
http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm
#################################################################
2015-11-19 13:59:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm>
{'address': [], 'city': [], 'library': [], 'phone': [], 'zip_code': []}
2015-11-19 13:59:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm>
{'address': [u'302 King Drive'],
 'city': [u'Albany'],
 'library': [u'Clinton County Public Library'],
 'phone': [u'(606) 387-5989'],
 'zip_code': [u'42602']}
2015-11-19 13:59:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm>
{'address': [u'1740 Central Avenue'],
 'city': [u'Ashland'],
 'library': [u'Boyd County Public Library'],
 'phone': [u'(606) 329-0090'],
 'zip_code': [u'41101']}
2015-11-19 13:59:58 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.publiclibraries.com/kentucky.htm>
{'address': [u'1016 Summit Road'],
 'city': [u'Ashland'],
 'library': [u'Summit Branch'],
 'phone': [u'(606) 928-3366'],
 'zip_code': []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scrapy` runs the requests asynchronously, and some requests could return before others, so `scrapy` works with the first request that returned successfully.

There are some different things that could be done to workaround this:

1. **Really execute one request after the other**

You could make a request, and then keep working with the following request after it finished using `meta`:

```
    urls = [response.urljoin(href.extract()) for href in response.xpath("//div/div/div/table/tr/td/a/@href")]
    yield Request(url[0], callback=self.parse_urls, meta=dict(urls=urls, index=0))

def parse_urls(self, response):
    # do your work with the current page
    yield Request(response.meta['urls'][response.meta['index']+1], 
        meta=dict(urls=response.meta['urls'], index=response.meta['index']+1))
```

2. **Set priority on the requests**

Every scrapy `Request` object has a `priority` attribute which can be changed anytime, so you could specify a priority while iterating:

```
    for i, href in enumerate(response.xpath("//div/div/div/table/tr/td/a/@href")):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_state_libs, priority=1000-i)
```

This should give a higher priority to the first request, but I think this doesn't completely assure what you want.

3. **Post process the order**

Maybe the more convenient, you could specify some index on the request, so you can later order it (also using `meta` or a field on an item).

Hope it helped.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to Scrapy, obviously--I think my next step is to really understand meta, since that is part of the solution I want. Thanks.

Comment: happy it helped, `meta` is just the way how to communicate between callbacks.